# How to use initializable iterators in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, iterator, dataset

I'm updating my code to work with TensorFlow >=2. However, I'm confused about how I should update my dataset pipeline, and in particular the initializable iterator.

Right now, my current implementation (tensorflow 1.12) looks like:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# ...

train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(raw_data)
train_data = train_data.batch(b_size)

iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_data.output_types, train_data.output_shapes)

input_data, output_data = iterator.get_next()
train_init = iterator.make_initializer(train_data)  # initializer for train_data
```

The neural network is fed with `input_data`, as:

```
model = UNet(input=input_data, name='UNet')
```

Finally, in my training loop I do:

```
with tf.Session(config=config) as Sess:
    # ...
    sess.run(train_init)  # initialize the dataset iterator
    sess.run(train_operation)  # run one forward pass
```

How should I update the code to work with TensorFlow 2.0?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: hi @edn, thanks for your comment :) in the end, I had to change the loading pipeline a bit. You can see the loading function at the GitHub link: https://github.com/gvalvano/GANs/blob/6e2f1c8e641f4458d00a9915347456d061e74100/data_interface/interfaces/acdc/acdc_paired_data_interface.py#L198 . I haven't used this code for a while, so there might be better approaches than my solution. Any feedback on your side is more than welcome! :)